# Difference between different scrollFlags for CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to learn about CollapsingToolbarLayout which has some value set to `scrollFlags` to control how the view within it will collapse. Can anybody clearly demarcate the difference between these flags:

- scroll
- enterAlways
- exitsUntilCollapsed
- enterAlwaysCollapsed
- enterAlways

How do these work when we set these flags to both Toolbar and CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Comment: Also see the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html

Answer (score 5):

I've made a table to clear things up. Also wrote quite an informative [blog post](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/appbarlayout-scroll-behavior-with-layout_scrollflags/) with an example code on [GitHub](https://github.com/lomza/AppBar-ScrollFlags-Example) :)

### **scroll**

***Scroll Up***: the view becomes visible when the layout's been scrolled all the way up
**Scroll Down**: the view scrolls with the rest of the content like it's a part of it; will hide if the layout's height is bigger than the screen's one

### **enterAlways**

**Scroll Up**: the view becomes visible on every scroll up action, even if there's still a lot of content to scroll up
**Scroll Down**: the view scrolls with the rest of the content like it's a part of it; will hide if the layout's height is bigger than the screen's one

### **enterAlwaysCollapsed**

**Scroll Up**: the collapsed version of the view (e.g. `Toolbar`) becomes visible on every scroll up action, and it expands (e.g. `Toolbar` with an `ImageView`) only when scrolled all the way up
**Scroll Down**: the view collapses and then hides, if the layout's height is bigger than the screen's one

### **exitUntilCollapsed**

**Scroll Up**: the view is always visible, provided its height is > 0 and the expanded version (e.g. Toolbar with an ImageView) will become visible when scrolled all the way up
**Scroll Down**: the view scrolls with the rest of the layout's content, but only till its collapsed state (hence - *"exit until collapsed"*), so in case of a `Toolbar` with a fixed height, it will always be visible on the top

### **snap**

**Scroll Up AND Down** fast scrolls up or down based on how much of the view is visible - if more than 50% - the view will scroll down, showing itself, if less - the view will hide; used with other flags as a further customization

Answer (score 3):

From Antonio Leiva's blog [here](http://antonioleiva.com/coordinator-layout/), the flags work like this:

> **scroll**: This means it will scroll while scrolling the targeted view (our recycler view in this case).
>
> **enterAlways**: When we scroll up, the view will immediately reappear.
>
> **enterAlwaysCollapsed**: if the view has a collapsed mode, it will reappear collapsed when scrolling up.
>
> **exitUntilCollapsed**: it won´t exit from the screen until the view is collapsed.

Comment: What would happen if collaspingToolbarLayout has flag of enterAlways | enterAlwaysCollapsed  and Toolabar has collapseMode set to pin. Is there some article that puts more light on it.

Comment: @user2779311, in this case on every scroll up action (even from the bottom  of the layout), Toolbar will show in a collapsed state, but will expand when scrolled all the way up. It will hide on scroll down as usual. What "pin" does is take your Toolbar (with action items and other stuff) and show it on scroll up, without "pin" a "naked" Toolbar would show.